# ASP.NET. HTML button causes a postback after exporting Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, postback, response

I have both asp.net server button controls and html buttons in my asp.net web form.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnExportToExcel" OnClick="btnExportToExcel_Click">Excel</asp:LinkButton>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Refresh</button>
```

I use asp.net button OnClick event to send back an Excel file. Below is the code:

```
 protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(ExcelHelper.GetByteArray(datatable));
    Response.End();
 }
```

The export to Excel works perfectly fine, but after the export is done, all html buttons start to cause a postback with target id of the asp.net button control responsible for the Excel export, i.e. the `OnClick` event of `btnExportToExcel` button is fired again and I get the same Excel file exported again.

Am i doing something wrong with the responce in the `OnClick` event? Or am I missing something else?

NB. I can fix the problem by using just asp.net buttons, but I would like to understand the nature of the problem.

EDIT. After the reply from Igor, is it correct that the problem has nothing to do  with the Response (i.e. I thought that the Response might be missing something) and it could be considered as an expected behavior and I need to be careful with the buttons I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens on your page:

1. `asp:LinkButton` is clicked. On its client-side click it calls `__doPostBack` that sets hidden `__EVENTTARGET` input value to `btnExportToExcel`.
2. The form is submitted to the server. Browser is waiting for the new content to arrive.
3. The new content is a downloadable file, so the browser page is not cleared and stays what it was during the submit.
4. Clicking on any button with `type="submit"` causes the form submission with `__EVENTTARGET` still having `btnExportToExcel` value.
5. Server-side page interprets `POST` request with `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]="btnExportToExcel"` as the click of `btnExportToExcel`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. How can I prevent this behavior from happening, i.e. how can I "clear" the __EVENTTARGET in the step 4?

Comment: @IgorShch - you already suggested one way to avoid this (at the end of your question). You can try adding javascript `onclick` handler to html buttons and clear `__EVENTTARGET` input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was trying to create a reusable "Export to Excel" solution for my company, so I was more worried about other people who will re-use it and face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing a [`Response.Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the beginning.

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(ExcelHelper.GetByteArray(datatable));
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. Unfortunately, it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - how does this help with wrongly targeted subsequent form submission?

Comment: @Igor: obviously not at all  since OP has commented that it doesn't solve the problem. I thought that it could fix it. However, it's important anyway.

Comment: cargo cult at its finest :)

Answer (score -1):

Add `OnServerClick="return false;"` to the button markup, to avoid the postback